# Inside a Fragment, what is the correct place to initialize OpenCV4Android?

Tags: opencv, android-fragments, android-context, android

The following snippet shows how OpenCV4Android is initialized in an `Activity`, e.g. in [this sample app](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java), but I need to do it inside a `Fragment` (because my `JavaCameraView` is in my Fragment).

I would do it just like that have done in the `Activity`, i.e. I would initialize `baseLoaderCallback` directly inside the class body (outside any method's body), but this way, the initializing code (4th statement in the following snippet) would be executed as soon as the `Fragment` is instantiated.

**As we can see, the `BaseLoaderCallback` constructor takes application context as an argument, and I can't call `getActivity()` before `onActivityCreated()` is called, because before `onActivityCreated()`, `getActivity()` can return null.**

```
public class AnActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    ...
    private JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    ...

    private CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;

    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                cameraBridgeViewBase.enableView();
                break;
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    ...

    //SOME LIFE CYCLE CALL BACK METHODS

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                baseLoaderCallback);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are initializing `baseLoaderCallback` in the class body (executed just before the constructor body), the callback's `onManagerConnected` is not called until the `OpenCVLoader.initAsync` completes, so not until `onResume`.

If you want to avoid calling `getActivity()` before `onAttach` (because it will return `null`), then just put the initializer for `baseLoaderCallback` in `onResume` since you don't really need it until then.

Comment: Yeah but `getActivity()` is called at that point (before the constructor), and `getActivity()` must not be called before `onActivityCreated()` - _that_ is the problem.

Comment: `getActivity()` is being called there because application context is needed there.

Comment: Ah, I updated my answer. If you are fine with calling `initAsync` in `onResume` then only initialize the `baseLoaderCallback` then.